# A good mac os x app delegate reference?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

Does anyone know any good app delegation reference? The type where it tells you the functions you can override and what they do? e.g

```
- (BOOL) ApplicationWillTerminateAfterLastWindowIsClosed{

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at XCode's built-in documentation? You can summon it by pressing Command+Option+Shift+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apple documentation. In each class reference you can easily find link to delegate protocol reference (if it exists). For example in [NSTableView class references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can see **Conforms to** section (at the top of document) with all links you need including link to NSTableViewDelegate protocol references.

It is implied that you know main features of class you used, so you need just to read at least first page of documentation for class. There you can find all you need.

Hope, it helps.